# Using of Firebase App Indexing and Dynamic Links for my use-case

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, firebase-app-indexing

I want to use App Indexing and Firebase Dynamic Links in my app. Is it possible to set these services to work in the following way:
App Indexing shows link to my app in Google Search results regardless the fact an app installed on users smartphone.
And if user don't have my app, system redirects him to App Store or Google Play.

And if this type of behavior isn't possible to set can I use Adwords for this scheme. I mean I use deeplink or dynamic link in my campaign? Is it possible through Adword's rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [App Indexing documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/):

> Firebase App Indexing gets your app into Google Search. *If users have your app installed*, they can launch your app and go directly to the content they're searching for. App Indexing reengages your app users by helping them find both public and personal content right on their device, even offering query autocompletions to help them more quickly find what they need. *If users don’t yet have your app*, relevant queries trigger an install card for your app in Search results.

That sounds like it matches your use-case, so I recommend you try it. If you're having problems while implementing, please report back with details on where you are stuck.